# Windows phone 7 login facebook

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, authentication

I'm developing facebook login in a windows phone application. I use Facebook SDK and it works perfect in the emulator, but the problem is in the mobile, I see the login form like this:

[image: login facebook]

I can't handle it because is part of Facebook SDK, so I don't know what to do to solve it. I tried to change "IsScriptEnabled" property of webbrowser control, but nothing changes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: how did you solve it I have similar issue?

Comment: To solve it you have to change the user-agent:      userAgent = "User-Agent: Mozilla 5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows Phone 7.5; Trident/5.0; IEMobile/9.0; ARM; Touch; NOKIA; Lumia 710)";  browser.Navigate(loginUrl, null, userAgent);